# What are the most elegant approximations of the sum of binomial terms, by using Stirling's approximation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation, approximation

What are the most elegant approximations by using Stirling's approximation for the sum of binomial terms as below?

$Sum(r) = \sum\limits_{k=r}^{n} \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$

I tried to plug in the approximation of factorial $x!$ into the formula, but the result looks crazily clumsy. Is there any elegant way to do this?

Many thanks!

Comment: There are a lot of different approximations depending on the precise range you want.  For your purposes how large is $r$? If $r$ is close to $n$ then this is easier to approximate.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. $r$ would be half of $n$. A typical one would be $\frac {n+1}{2}$ when $n$ is odd.

Answer (score 2):

From 'Decoding Generalized Hyperoctohedral Groups and Asymptotic Analysis of Correctible Error Patterns,' R. Bailey and T. Prellberg, Contribut. Discrete Math. vol. 7 # 1, p 1-14 (2012). The following asymptotic expression is derived:

Define
$$ F_{m,r}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^r{\binom{m}{k}x^k} $$
$$ \beta=r/m \text{ with } 0<\beta<1$$
$$ \rho(\beta,x)=\sqrt{\log{(1+x)}  - \beta \, \log{x} + \beta\log{\beta} + (1-\beta)\log{(1-\beta}) } $$
Then
$$ F_{m,r}(x) \sim (1+x)^m \frac{1}{2} \text{erfc}\big( \sqrt{m}\, \rho(\beta, x) \big) $$
The paper gives the next term in the expansion as well.  The sign associated with $\rho$ because of the square root is tricky.  I did the math once and I believe it is equivalent to $\text{sign}(x-\beta/(1-\beta))$.

Your problem can be reduced to this one by using the full binomial theorem and subtracting the 'head' of the series.  Of course, to use this formula $x=p/(1-p)$ and there will be an external factor of $(1-p)^n.$

Comment: 9/26/2018

When I wrote this I tested the approximation with $\beta$ > 0.6 and for several $0<x<1.$ In this region the formula appears to work well.  For $\beta$ < 1/2 and $x$ in the upper range, this formula seems to be off by a factor that can get disturbingly high.  For example, let m=400 and r=50.  Then for x=1/10 $F_{400,50}(1/10)/'approx' = 1.0029$, acceptable to me for most situations.  However for x=9/10 and the same m,n, $F_{400,50}(9/10)/'approx' = 2.685.$  I would not find this discrepancy satisfactory.  There must be some implicit assumption in the paper's setup that precludes this formula from being universally applicable.